# VueJs: Wrapping el-select: list elements added 3 times during DOM refreshes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I've encapsulated some of the excellent [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/2.8/#/en-US/component/installation) components. Since I generally use the same settings all over the place. Plus I wanted to have cleaner code. All are working OK, except the `el-select` where I get a DOM error about duplicate keys.

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'XXX VALUE'. This may cause an update error.
```

[image]

Originally I just passed the list direct to the `<el-select>` got the same errors, then made a `localList` var, same thing.

I've added nextTick in the mounted section, there is a full example here.

The contents of the list get added **3 times**, hence the error.
[image]

```js
// Please note: The original code is a .vue component, modified it for this example.

Vue.component('select-input', {
  props: {
    label: {
     type: String,
     default: 'Select'
    },

  value: {
      required: true
    },

    list: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    },
    
    disabled: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    init () {
      this.localList = this.list
    },

    updated (value) {
      this.form = value
      this.$emit('input', this.form)
      this.$emit('change', this.form)
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      form: this.value,
      localList: []
    }
  },


  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick().then(this.init())
  },

  template: '<el-form-item :label="label" v-if="localList"><el-select v-if="!disabled" v-model="form" placeholder="Select..." :disabled="disabled" @change="updated"><el-option v-if="item[valueKey]" v-for="item in localList" :label="item[labelValue]":value="item[valueKey]" :key="item[valueKey]" /><el-option v-else v-for="(item, index) in list" :label="item" :value="item" :key="index" /></el-select> <b v-else>{{this.form}}</b></el-form-item>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    select1: null,
    select2: null,
    list: ['Minutes', 'Hours', 'Days']
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.8.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<!-- import JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.8.2/lib/index.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="app">
  <h3>Normal Select Works OK</h3>
  <el-select v-model="select1" placeholder="Select...">
    <el-option v-for="item in list" :value="item" :key="item"></el-option>
  </el-select>
 
  <p>You chose: <b>{{select1}}</b></p>
  
  <hr />

  <h3>Wrapped Component Select Works Gives Errors</h3>
  <p><i>See browser console</i></p>

  <el-form>
    <select-input label="Period" v-model="select2" :list="list"></select-input>
  </el-form>
  <p>You chose: <b>{{select2}}</b></p>
  

</div>



</body>
```

Comment: Could it be that something else is corrupting the list, external to the code provided? Lots of routes of investigation but they all start with establishing whether the array itself is getting mangled. Try using `Object.freeze` to stop it changing. Try dumping it out in the template using `{{ list }}`. What if you use `this.localList = ['Minutes', 'Hours', 'Days']` instead? The order in the picture is different from the code (M/H/D, not H/M/D). Not entirely clear why you're aliasing `list` to `localList`, they will both refer to the same object so changing one will change the other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @skirtle the order of the list is different simply because I typed them in that order for the example. Good catch though. I've checked the list integrity, it's not getting changed, what's happening is <el-option> is being called 3 times with the same data, because of my `v-if` condition (which is not in the example), I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it- as suspected the **v-else** condition was the problem. Since with a simple list, rather than an object array with label, value pairs, it would go the the else condition.

```
<el-option v-if="item[valueKey]" v-for="item in localList"
 :label="item[labelValue]":value="item[valueKey]" :key="item[valueKey]" />

<el-option v-else v-for="(item, index) in list"
  :label="item" :value="item" :key="index" />
```

If the component gets a plain list, it now processes it so it can be processed as follows:

```
<el-option v-for="item in localList"
 :label="item[labelValue]":value="item[valueKey]" :key="item[valueKey]" />
```

I guess I was trying to be too clever by half!

Answer (score 0):

try this

your v-for loop key is item try to change it to index like this

```
<el-option v-for="(item, index) in localList" :label="item" :value="item" :key="index" /> </el-select>
```

Comment: thanks **sid heart** just tried that- I now get `Duplicate keys detected: '0'. This may cause an update error` and so on for each key.

Comment: I've kinda figured it out, I excluded from the sample a `v-if` and `v-else` around whether it's a simple list or a structured object list. that seems be be causing the problems.